# How to compare File Names in directory to File Names in list object and copy to new directory

Tags: c#

I need to compare all files in a directory to file names in a list.
In the example below, the file `x.txt` does not `exist` in the directory.

I need to use a single `foreach` loop. However, the files are copying even when the list do not match. I only need the files copy if the list matched to all files.

Here is an example code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dir = @"C:\example\";
        string backupDir = @"C:\exampleBackup\";

        var files = new List<string> { "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "x.txt" };

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if(!File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, file)))
            {

           //do this only if the list and directory matches

                Console.Write("Directory and List do not match:\n");
                break;
            }

          //If the list does not match the directory or either way then do this.
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Directory and List Match:\n");

         //if match then copy files to new directory
         File.Copy(Path.Combine(dir, file), Path.Combine(backupDir, file), true);
         }
       }

        Console.Write("Enter any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried? It seems like a simple logic change - determine if all files are present first, then only copy them if that's the case. What makes you think you "need to use a single `foreach` loop" ?

Comment: It looks like the code is work. What is your question? What exactly do you want to improve in the example?

Comment: Some files are still being copied when the list does not match. I only need to copy all files when both the list and directory matches, meaning the names and number of files.